# Common place symbol that means power or strength

Tags: icons, symbols

In the gaming community, both digital and physical, we all recognise that a heart symbol represents 'health' or 'life', but which symbol is common use for 'strength' or 'power'?

For my specific example the symbol will be places on a printed card.
The card displays the Base strength. You then choose how many multipliers to use. Whoever has the largest number wins the round.

Comment: You should not ask open ended questions about what icon to use - please read the tour: http://ux.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Hi Steve. I don't feel the question is open ended. It's basically asking what the standard icon for strength or power.

Comment: Hi Terry - I was just quoting this extract from the UX:SO tour "Don't ask about...

Open-ended recommendations (What's a good icon for... What software is good for...)"

Comment: Ah right. If that's the case I'll remove my question. How do I delete in the app?

Comment: This community can vote to close it, I guess. To answer you question however, the most common symbol is the "strong arm". You will easily spot it by googling "strength icon"

Comment: You're talking about the gaming community, does this mean you are looking for an icon for a game? Because strength as in humans being fit is probably going to have a much different answer than strength in a game.

Comment: The icon is for a card game. The symbol will denote Base strength of the cards.

Comment: Strength is ambiguous. What you want to do? Does strength helps better defending? then Armour sigh. Does strength mean attack power? then sword or gun. Does strength mean life/power/energy? then heart icon. I am talking from games perspective. A more detailed approach towards what that strength does is more helpful for your users.

Comment: The card displays the Base strength. You then choose how many multpiers rs to use. Whoever has the largest wins the round.

Comment: @Terry It's probably going to depend on what is most suitable for your gametype, if it's a fantasy type game, probably something with a sword or magical icon. If it's more realistic/shooter related maybe a gun or an icon similar to what SteveD showcases below.

Comment: @Terry search for hearthstone screenshots, they use a drip shape which is red (a drip of blood) as a health icon, and a yellow icon with a sword behind it for combat power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the most common symbol for "strength"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Strength and power can be represented at
**close fist:** *https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.primusdatabase.com%2Fimages%2F6%2F69%2FBlack-power-fist-icon.png&psig=AFQjCNGXMiefy8OMISkZFumKHqeAGJ0H4w&ust=1472204222009104&cad=rja*

**Flash sign**: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=&url=http%3A%2F%2Ficons.iconarchive.com%2Ficons%2Fmysitemyway%2Fclean-3d%2F256%2Fglossy-3d-blue-power-icon.png&psig=AFQjCNGXMiefy8OMISkZFumKHqeAGJ0H4w&ust=1472204222009104